# How can I access any element in a web page with Python?

Tags: python, cgi, html-parsing

I would like to access any element in a web page. I know how to do that when I have a form (`form = cgi.FieldStorage()`), but not when I have, for example, a table.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "element" and "web page"

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with javascript, you should be familiar with the DOM. [This](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) should help you to get the information you want, seeing how this parses HTML, among other things. Then it's up to you to extract the information you need

Answer (score 0):

HTML parsing using either `HTMLParser` or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) if you're trying to get data from a web page. You can't really write data to an HTML table like you could do with CGI and forms, so I'm hoping this is what you want.

I personally recommend Beautiful Soup if you want intelligent parsing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access a table is to [parse](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) the HTML. This is different from accessing form data, in that it's not dynamic. Since you mentioned CGI, I'm assuming you're working on the server side of things and that you have the ability to serve whatever content you want. So you could use whatever data you're representing in the table in its raw form before turning it into HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

You can access only data, posted by form (or as GET parameters).

So, you can extract data you need using JavaScript and post it through form